# Making a dynamic connection to database server

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have received a ready virtual flight booking system from one friend to use it and it's based on 2 databases under 1 username and password.

The problem that is my host is generating a unique **host, username and password** for each database. The good thing in this system is all the connection scripts are in one file and I have modified most of parts but I stuck on the main part; function change_db.

Here is mysqlexec code first:

```
<?php
$ini = parse_ini_file("data.ini.php");
$host_rfe    = $ini["host_rfe"];
$host_nav    = $ini["host_nav"];
$rfedatabase = $ini["rfedatabase"];
$navdatabase = $ini["navdatabase"];
$login_db_rfe    = $ini["login_db_rfe"];
$pass_db_rfe     = $ini["pass_db_rfe"];
$login_db_nav    = $ini["login_db_nav"];
$pass_db_nav     = $ini["pass_db_nav"];
$port        = $ini["port"];

// Connecting to Database
if(!($sqlconn=@mysql_connect("$host_rfe:$port",$login_db_rfe,$pass_db_rfe))) {
    echo "<p align=\"center\"><big><img src=\"images/redx.png\"><br/><strong>It wasn't possible to connect to MySQL server. Please, check the configurations.</strong></big></p>";
    exit;
}

// Select Database
if(!($con=@mysql_select_db($rfedatabase,$sqlconn))) {
    echo "<p align=\"center\"><big><img src=\"images/redx.png\"><br/><strong>It wasn't possible to connect to database <i>$rfedatabase</i>. Please, check the configurations.</strong></big></p>";
    exit;
}

/*========================================================================
 Function: change_db
    Usage: This function changes the pointer to another MySQL Database
Arguments:
    $sqlconn - Connection pointer
    $db      - Destnation's database
========================================================================*/
function change_db($sqlconn,$db) {

    global $sqlconn;

    if(!($con=mysql_select_db($db,$sqlconn))) {
        echo "<p align=\"center\"><big><img src=\"images/redx.png\"><br/><strong>It wasn't possible to connect to database <i>$db</i>. Please, check the configurations.</strong></big></p>";
        exit;
    }

    return $con;
}
?>
```

The system will need to connect always to both database depend on the functions. Initially the connection is with **$rfedatabase** and then it needs to swap to **$rfedatabase** and then may go back to first, so on. To do the database swapping, the system uses the function change_db. Example:

```
change_db($sqlconn,$navdatabase);
--some functions--
change_db($sqlconn,$rfedatabase);
--some functions--
```

So here comes the issue with **global $sqlconn;**. The connection will be always to **$rfedatabase** host and will not switch to the other one.

I have changed **global $sqlconn;** with this code but did not work:

```
if($db == $rfedatabase){
    $sqlconn=mysql_connect("$host_rfe:$port",$login_db_rfe,$pass_db_rfe);
    exit;
} else {
    $sqlconn=mysql_connect("$host_nav:$port",$login_db_nav,$pass_db_nav);
    exit;
}
```

Any idea how to make the connection relevant to the needed database?

Comment: The old `mysql_...()` functions are outdated and have been marked as deprecated long ago.

Comment: Yup. Please stop using `mysql_*()` functions (see [warning at the top of this page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)) and consider using [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`pdo_mysql`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) instead.

Comment: I am aware of using mysqli, is just changing the whole scripts will take little time and am working it. I just want to know what is the wrong of my replacing of global $sqlconn above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I found the issue, I just forgot to do SQL Pointer to my global variable.

```
global $rfedatabase, $navdatabase, $host_rfe, $host_nav, $port, $login_db_rfe, $pass_db_rfe, $login_db_nav, $pass_db_nav;

if($db == $rfedatabase){
    $sqlconn=mysql_connect("$host_rfe:$port",$login_db_rfe,$pass_db_rfe);
} else {
    $sqlconn=mysql_connect("$host_nav:$port",$login_db_nav,$pass_db_nav);
}
```